# Is there a good reason to use metaprogramming to modify the return type of a method?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

Say you have a method:

```
boolean test() { return true; }
```

Would it ever be a good idea to use metaprogramming to change it to return a String:

```
String test() {return "test"}
```

I think using metaprogramming for that is confusing and should be avoided since it changes the public interface that calling code expects.  Does anyone have an example of when it would be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are dynamically returning different types it would make more sense to just type the method return as `def` such as:

```
def test() {
   if (something) {
        return true
   } else {
        return 'test'
   }
}
```

So to answer your question, no I do not think it would ever be a good idea. :)